# XMLRPC server compilation problem in linux

Tags: xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver

```
CC -Wall -g `xmlrpc-c-config client abyss-server --cflags`   `xmlrpc-c-config client abyss-server --libs`   xmlrpc_sample_add_server.c   -o xmlrpc_sample_add_server
```

above is command line command I used to compile xmlrpc_sample_add_server.c  but I get this error,

```
    xmlrpc_sample_add_server.c:11: fatal error: xmlrpc-c/server_abyss.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SRCDIR = $(CURDIR)/..
BLDDIR = $(SRCDIR)
XMLRPC_C_CONFIG = $(BLDDIR)/xmlrpc-c-config.test

all: xmlrpc_sample_add_server

xmlrpc_sample_add_server : xmlrpc_sample_add_server.o
        gcc -Wall -g -o xmlrpc_sample_add_server xmlrpc_sample_add_server.o   $(shell $(XMLRPC_C_CONFIG) abyss-server --libs) 

xmlrpc_sample_add_server.o : xmlrpc_sample_add_server.c
        gcc -Wall -g -c -I. $(shell $(XMLRPC_C_CONFIG) client abyss-server --cflags)    xmlrpc_sample_add_server.c 

clean:
        rm -rf *.o xmlrpc_smaple_add_server
```

Found the answer...

for some reason one would have to make the object first then compile based on the object...